# $X$, $Y$ Hausdorff spaces and $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to X$ continuous with $g\circ f=1_X$. Show that $f(X)$ is closed

Tags: general-topology

The following is part of an exercise from *Dugundji's Topology* book. It is apparently simple, but I'm stuck in it.

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be Hausdorff spaces and $f:X\to Y$, $g:Y\to X$ be continuous maps such that $g\circ f=1_X$. Show that $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$.

Comment: It suffices to assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff. In fact, $f$ is an embedding since it has a left inverse. Therefore $X$ is automatically Hausdorff is $Y$ is. See also Warlock of Firetop Mountain's answer. Moreover note that $f$ is a **closed map** because it establishes a homeomorphism between $X$ and the closed subset $f(X) \subset Y$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider the map 
$$h:Y\to X\times Y \to Y\times Y$$
$$ y\mapsto (g(y),y) \mapsto (f(g(y), y)$$
it is a continuous map from $Y\to Y\times Y$ because is composition and product of continuous maps. Since Y is Hausdorff the diagonal $\Delta_Y\subset Y\times Y$ is closed.  Therefore $f(X) = h^{-1}(\Delta_Y)$ gives the conclusion.

Comment: +1 IMHO, all proofs that use the Hausdorff property in the form of "$\Delta$ is closed" have an inherent elegance

Answer (score 2):

Assume a net $\{f(x_{\delta})\}$ is such that $f(x_{\delta})\rightarrow y$, then continuity of $g$ implies $g(f(x_{\delta}))\rightarrow g(y)$. On the other hand,  $g(f(x_{\delta}))=x_{\delta}$, so $x_{\delta}\rightarrow g(y)$. So continuity of $f$ implies $f(x_{\delta})\rightarrow f(g(y))$. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, we have $y=f(g(y))$, as $f(g(y))\in f(X)$, so $y\in f(X)$.

Comment: Any other way without using "nets"?